# Rails: Multitenant database can't find record in public schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord, multi-tenant

## Background

So I have a Rails application with a multitenant database (single db, multiple schemas), using the [Apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/). What this does is creates and finds schema names based on a list that you point to in its configuration file. In my case, those names are pointing to attributes on my `Organization` table. This table has a `subdomain` column that determines the names of the schemas.

So for instance, I have one `Organization` per schema. A few example schema names I have are `public`, `tool`, and `pendulum`. These schemas are created upon the creation of the `Organization` record, and all tables you specify in the config file are scoped to that schema.

There are certain tables that are excluded from the multitenant configuration, like `users`. They exist in the `public` schema and are accessible by all other schemas (at least that's how I understand it). In my case, `Organization` is one of these excluded tables.

## My problem

When I try to set a reference from one schema-specific table (let's say `Tour` for instance) to an organization, I get the following ActiveRecord (Rails' built-in ORM strategy) error:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "events" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_163b5130b5"
DETAIL:  Key (organization_id)=(2) is not present in table "organizations".
```

## Debugging

The primary key of the `Organization` I'm trying to set as the foreign key on the `Tour` is 2.

Here's some relevant output from my console:

```
Apartment::Tenant.current
=> "public"

Organization.count
  (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "public"."organizations"
=> 1

Organization.last.id
  Organization Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "public"."organizations".* FROM "public"."organizations" ORDER BY "public"."organizations"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> 2

Apartment::Tenant.switch!('tool')
=> nil

Organization.count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "public"."organizations"
=> 1

Organization.last.id
  Organization Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "public"."organizations".* FROM "public"."organizations" ORDER BY "public"."organizations"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> 2
```

So Apartment seems to be correctly only looking for the organizations in the `public` schema, and it's only finding one each time.

However, after going into the psql CLI...

```
select * from public.organizations;

id | user_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         | name | subdomain
----+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------+-----------
 2 |       1 | 2019-06-05 19:07:34.457148 | 2019-06-05 19:07:34.457148 | Tool | tool      
(1 row)

select * from tool.organizations;

id | user_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         | name | subdomain
----+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------+-----------
 1 |       1 | 2019-04-15 09:46:55.239833 | 2019-04-15 09:46:55.239833 | Tool | tool      
(1 row)
```

Yes, I created an organization earlier and deleted it. And for some reason it appears to be showing up in `tool.organizations` rather than `public.organizations`. When I created it, I'm 100% sure that organizations was still scoped to the public schema.

Oddly, though, the rails console is still telling me that the organization in the public schema with id of 2 doesn't exist. When it clearly does. The tour I'm trying to updated is in fact scoped to the `tool` schema, but as is evident from the above queries, it shouldn't matter which schema I'm trying to update from. The organizations table exists in `public`, and shouldn't be scoped to `tool`, no matter where you are...

What am I missing?

Comment: Didn't read it all, but it must be a `search_path` problem. Tables are created in the first schema on the `search_path` where you have `CREATE` permissions, and read from the first schema in `search_path` that contains a table of that name and where you have `USAGE` permissions.